# Android Studio - Unable to debug application

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

I'm working with a device running Android 5.1 and using Android Studio 3.4.1.
I've enabled developer options on my device. See image below.

[image]

Now when I connect the USB cable from my Android device to my windows machine and click on the debug icon in Android Studio I get the following errors/messages:

```
 05/23 09:18:20: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\nortonj\Documents\Projects\AndroidApps\transact_esn_registration\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/TransAct.AccuDate.ESN_SN.Registration
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK
```

See image below of my Android Studio window.

[image]

And in the "Select Deployment Target" dialog I see the following:

[image]

So a few questions:

1. Why does my device show as being [OFFLINE]?
2. I'm new to Android Development. What steps do I need to take to be able to debug this application on my hardware device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The device share files with PC
2. Device is enabled debug mode
3. Look gradle/app

   buildTypes {
       debug {
          debuggable true
       }
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
           proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please go into a bit more detail? I'm not sure I totally understand what you are telling me is wrong with my setup. Regards.

Comment: post your app/build.gradle